# Displaying data from custom fields on a specific category page

Tags: categories, custom-field, post-meta

I created custom fields on my functions.php page and use the values from these fields on a template-parts page (for activities). This works fine. I would like to have a page for each category showing all the activities for that category. I succesfully loaded my template on category.php, which shows my HTML template on homepage/category/name-category.

However, when I try to load the values from the same custom fields as I use on my general activities page (in template-parts), this doesn't work. I did some tests, printed the ID of the category to make sure I'm on the right page. It prints all the html fine but only the custom fields values are missing.

PHP on category.php page

```
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
            $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

            $category_id = get_cat_ID('Seasonal Events');
            //print($category_id);
            //print($cat_id);
    if($category_id == $cat_id){    
             $value_title = get_post_meta($post -> ID, '_activities_title', true);
             $value_description = get_post_meta($post -> ID, '_activities_description', true);

             print($value_title);
             print($value_description);


        }
```

The ID of the category I'm testing with (which has several posts in it) is 3 and $category_id & $cat_id both return 3 as well.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I've been trying to find a solution for a while but I'm stuck on this!

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Please check whether `$post` is a global variable or not. Try putting `echo  $post->ID` and check. If you see nothing, you better use the function `get_the_ID()` rather than `$post->ID`.

Comment: I don't seem to get a return value from either of those, the weird thing is that on any other page the custom field values work fine but on this page they just don't work at all.

Comment: This is a indication of missing post loop. Your code should go inside a post loop. A post loop looks like `while(have_posts()): the_posts(); /* your code */ endwhile;`